# Multi variable pricing in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I sell custom T-Shirts and I need a plugin to set up pricing system that takes the input from one of the product options a user selects and then serves up pricing breaks based on quantity.

Let me explain:

1. Customer selects product
2. Customer uploads their design want printed on their shirt then selects from a dropdown menu how many colors are in the design
3. Depending on their choice they get a quantity based pricing table

Here is an example:

Customer chooses a 2 color design for their shirts

If they order:

1-10 Shirts, the price is 10 per shirt.

11-20 Shirts, the price is 9 per shirt.

21-30 Shirts, the price is 8 per shirt.

31-40 Shirts, the price is 7 per shirt.

and so on..

However if they choose a 3 color design for their shirts

If they order:

1-10 Shirts, the price is 11 per shirt.

11-20 Shirts, the price is 10 per shirt.

21-30 Shirts, the price is 9 per shirt.

31-40 Shirts, the price is 8 per shirt.

and so on..

If anyone can help by recommending a plugin or a developer who can build me a plugin i'd be extremely grateful

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in two sections :

1. For multiple colors to allow for user selection, you can create different variants for a product. For e.g. 
   Product A - Variation 1 with 3 color design - variation 2 with 5 color design etc.
2. Regarding quantity based pricing, you can define quantity based prices for each variation using this plugin https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing/

I hope this helps!